# Ninject to Simple Injector: Register ActionFilter with Controller Attribute (with params)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have an WebApi application that uses Simple Injector and I'm trying to configure a particular filter with controller attribute (with parameters). I have this configuration working in another project that uses Ninject, but I don't know how to do this on Simple Injector.

```
public enum UserType {
    Director,
    Developer,
    Leader
}
```

My controller:

```
[RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypes(UserType.Developer, UserType.Leader)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

My Attribute:

```
public sealed class RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UserType[] TypesToBeVerified { get; set; }

    public RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesAttribute(params UserType[] typesToBeVerified)
    {
        TypesToBeVerified = typesToBeVerified;
    }
}
```

My Filter:

```
public class RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IUser _user;
    private readonly UserType[] _typesToBeVerified;

    protected RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter(IUser user, params UserType[] typesToBeVerified)
    {
        _user = user;
        _typesToBeVerified = typesToBeVerified;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool authorized = _user.HasAtLeastOneOfTypes(_typesToBeVerified);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            throw new ForbiddenUserException();
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

And finally my Ninject configuration:

```
this.BindFilter<RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
    .WhenControllerHas<RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesAttribute>()
    .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesAttribute>(
        "typesToBeVerified",
         attribute => attribute.typesToBeVerified);
```

My question is: How can I do this configuration using Simple Injector?

Comment: @Transcendent Yes, sure! As I wrote, I'm using Simple Injector on my project and trying to bind a filter on the same way someone did in another project (that uses Ninject).

Comment: What you are trying to do has 2 design problems. Read 
[this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2014/dependency-injection-in-attributes-dont-do-it/) and [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simple Injector Web API integration packages don't contain an integration feature for action filters as Ninject's integration package does. But such integration can be built in a few lines of code.

There are a few options here. The first option is to revert to resolving services directly from inside your action filter, as demonstrated inside the [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#injecting-dependencies-into-web-api-filter-attributes). This approach is fine when you have a single filter class, but isn't the cleanest approach, and would force you to make changes to your already created filter attribute.

As a second option you can, therefore, create a action filter proxy class, that is able to forward the call to your real filter class, which can than be resolved by Simple Injector:

```cs
public class ActionFilterProxy<T> : IActionFilter
    where T : IActionFilter
{
    public ActionFilterProxy(Container container) => _container = container;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) =>
        _container.GetInstance<T>().OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) =>
        _container.GetInstance<T>().OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Using this proxy, you can make the following configuration:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(
    new ActionFilterProxy<RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter>(container));

container.Register<RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter>();
```

This still forces you to make a change to `RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter`, because Simple Injector can't provide the attribute's information (the `UserType[]`) to `RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter`'s constructor. Instead,you can change `RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter` to the following:

```cs
public class RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IUser _user;

    public RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesFilter(IUser user) => _user = user;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Get the attribute from the controller here
        var attribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttribute<RequiresAtLeastOneOfUserTypesAttribute>();

        bool authorized = _user.HasAtLeastOneOfTypes(attribute.TypesToBeVerified);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            throw new ForbiddenUserException();
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

A third option to use is the one referred to in the [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#injecting-dependencies-into-web-api-filter-attributes), which is described in [this blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2014/dependency-injection-in-attributes-dont-do-it/), which discusses a model where you place your filters behind an application-specific abstraction and allow them to be Auto-Registered. It uses the a similar proxy approach. This method is useful when you have multiple/many filters that need to be applied (where their order of execution is irrelevant).

Comment: Hi Steven! Thank you so moch, but I'm still having troubles. As I am using WebApi, some classes you mentioned don't exist, such as ActionExecutingContext for example. I tried to use the WebMvc ones, but the OnActionExecuting method didn't fired.

Comment: The example filter indeed uses MVC, but that's merely because I noticed you were using MVC in your question. But rewriting it for pure Web API shouldn't be difficult, conceptually it works the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a few changes and all code is working like a charm! Regards!